# INC AL is not incrementing by 1

Tags: node.js, assembly

I am trying to convert assembly code into nodejs.

But I am currently stuck on a `INC AL` suddenly making AL 0xCA, then 0xCB.

Here is the ASM:

```
CMP AL, DL // DL = 09, AL = 35
JA SHORT   // jump is taken
SUB DL,AL  // ---> jumped
JMP SHORT  // ---> jumped
NOT AL     // AL = 35
INC AL     // AL = CA (which is 202)
ADD DL, AL // AL = CB, DL = 09
```

Now how did `INC AL` make 35 into CA? Isn't `inc` suppose to be `i++`?

My nodejs code:

```
// cmp al, dl
if (b <= a) {
  a -= b;
} else {
  // a++;
  a += 0xcb;
}
```

Comment: The values shown in the comments are *before* the instruction executes, not after.

Comment: @mbratch oh, that is why.

Comment: if your values are unsigned, you can't be getting `-36`. You're going to need to show your updated code in the problem statement, including variable declarations. Also please show where the `SHORT` label is in the assembly language. The `if-else` looks incorrect based upon what you show so far, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @mbratch I opened another question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767680/nodejs-bitwise-operator-from-c-asm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT AL` is bitwise inverting your value.

```
NOT(35) -> CA    00110101 -> 11001010
INC(CA) -> CB
```

Comment: Whoa, I missed that. New in asm though. Thanks. I can accept the answer in 11min.

Comment: No idea how/why node would be putting a `NOT` in there, since you don't have a not in the code, e.g. `a = !a`.

Comment: the code actually came from a C program I am trying to convert to node.

Comment: It looks to me like the C code shown in the OP's problem statement was been changed since the assembly code was derived, or vice versa.

Comment: using `~` turned `35` to `-36` why not `CA`?

Comment: I still cant get the correct value via my nodejs code. What could I be missing. can accept in 4min.

Comment: depends on if your C variable is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @MarcB Oh. I see. all my values are unsigned on the c code.

Comment: @MarcB @mbratch still can't convert 35 to CA. Why is that? even using `readUInt8` it returns the same int value of 53.

Comment: @majimboo if `a` is `unsigned char` and its value is initially `0x35` and you do `a = ~a;` that should do the complement. But if you look at all three instructions, `NOT AL`, `INC AL`, and `ADD DL,AL`, what those together are really doing is subtracting the original `AL` from `DL`. So I think the real meaning of that code is, `b -= a`. But it's a little convoluted. You should show the asm code that follows, in case it depends on some X86 flag settings.