# NodeJS bitwise operator from C ASM

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, assembly

This is related to my previews [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766731/inc-al-is-not-incrementing-by-1/22766768).

A complete ASM of the function in C is [here](http://pastebin.com/20dCWMpK).

My problem lies on:

```
00408091  |>  F6D3          ||NOT BL
00408093  |.  FEC3          ||INC BL
00408095  |.  02D3          ||ADD DL,BL
```

On javascript when I use the NOT bitwise operator on `0x35` it returns `-36` instead of the expected `0xCA`. Why is that?

```
  // cmp al, dl
  if (b <= a) {
    a -= b;
  } else {
    // problem lies here
    console.log(~b);
    a += b;
    a++;
  }
```

My nodejs code currently is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < hashed.length; i++) {
  var a = hashed[i];
  var b = seqX[i];
  var c = seqX[i+1];

  var stepIn = i+1;
  var stepOver = stepIn-1;

  // cmp BL, DL -- 0x63, 0x4e -- 0xf9, 0xc5 -- 0x75. 0x7a
  for (var j = internalRounds - 1; j > 0; j--, stepIn--, stepOver--) {
    if (seqX[(i*2)+1] <= a) {
      a -= seqX[(i*2)+1];
    } else {
      a += seqX[(i*2)+1];
      a++
    }
    // xor dl, bl -- 0x1c, 0xc0
    a ^= seqY[stepIn];
  }

  // cmp al, dl
  if (b <= a) {
    a -= b;
  } else {
    // problem lies here
    console.log(~b);
    a += b;
    a++;
  }

  // xor al, dl --- 0xd4, 0xb8
  a ^= seqY[i];

  // xor al, cl
  a ^= 0x6e;

  console.log(a.toString(16)); // I expect this to be 2.
  console.log('--------------------------');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sequence of instructions:

```
00408091  |>  F6D3          ||NOT BL
00408093  |.  FEC3          ||INC BL
00408095  |.  02D3          ||ADD DL,BL
```

Is treating the bytes in `BL` and `DL` as signed values and essentially subtracting `BL` from `DL`. The first two take the 2's complement negation of `BL` as a byte, then the third adds the negated `BL` to `DL`. Unless there are subsequent instructions that deal a certain way with the processor status flags, I'm not sure why it doesn't just say, `SUB DL,BL`.

So I would think this group of instructions would just translate into:

```
b -= a;
```

Rather than literally translating each instruction.

This depends somewhat on the context of the whole asm program, how `BL` and `DL` are treated. If they are treated as byte values consistentlyt, then the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

That because javascript always operates with 32-bit signed integers. So you have to truncate result to 8 bits.

```
(~0x35) & 0xFF // results 0xCA
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two problems.  The first is that you are doing `~35`, not `0x35` (the first is decimal 35, the second hex 35).

The second is that the bitwise-not in javascript casts the argument to a 32-bit signed integer, whereas it appears that you expect it to be treated as an unsigned char (8-bits).  You can fix this by taking the result of the not and doing a bitwise-and with `0xFF`.  So:

```
(~0x35) & 0xFF
> 202
((~0x35) & 0xFF).toString(16)
> "ca"
```